# WidgetKit iOS 17 - getCurrentConfigurations returned configuration is nil

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, xcode15, ios17

Widget configuration is nil in returned data from getCurrentConfigurations function.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        WidgetCenter.shared.getCurrentConfigurations { result in
            print(result)
        }
        return true
    }
```

iOS 17 result:

> success([WidgetInfo: - configuration: nil - widgetConfigurationIntent: nil - family: systemLarge - kind: WidgetBugSampleExtension])

Widget configuration view:

[image]

iOS 16 works fine. [Sample project reproducing the problem](https://github.com/2poy/widget-bug-sample)

Comment: Sample works fine in iOS 17.2

Comment: Thanks for checking @RTXGamer . That's odd. What Xcode version do you have? Can you please share your print message from AppDelegate?

Comment: Just faced a similar bug. Not working on iOS 17.2 - returns nil for all configurations.